# [node, @react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]` finished with an exception. Error message: groovy.json.JsonException

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradlew, react-native-cli

**Description**
Previously I wanted to continue to finish my React Native Android application, but after running it, an error like this has never happened before:

**Error Details**
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\KonselingTelyu\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 450
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Calling `[node, D:\KonselingTelyu\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]` finished with an exception. Error message: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

The current character read is 'i' with an int value of 105
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 0
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
^. Output: info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 24s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\KonselingTelyu\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 450
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Calling `[node, D:\KonselingTelyu\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]` finished with an exception. Error message: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

The current character read is 'i' with an int value of 105
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 0
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
^. Output: info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 24s

```
at makeError (D:\KonselingTelyu\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\KonselingTelyu\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\KonselingTelyu\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\KonselingTelyu\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

- **react-native info**

> D:\KonselingTelyu>react-native info
> info Fetching system and libraries information...
> (node:4328) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> System:
> OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
> CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
> Memory: 6.69 GB / 11.90 GB
> Binaries:
> Node: 18.12.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
> Yarn: Not Found
> npm: 9.7.2 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
> Watchman: Not Found
> SDKs:
> Android SDK:
> API Levels: 28, 30, 31, 33
> Build Tools: 28.0.3, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0
> System Images: android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
> Android NDK: Not Found
> Windows SDK: Not Found
> IDEs:
> Android Studio: Version     2020.3.0.0 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000
> Visual Studio: Not Found
> Languages:
> Java: 11.0.17
> npmPackages:
> @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
> react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0
> react-native: 0.70.6 => 0.70.6
> react-native-windows: Not Found
> npmGlobalPackages:
> *react-native*: Not Found

- **npm list @react-native-community/cli**

> KonselingTelyu@0.0.1 D:\KonselingTelyu
> `-- react-native@0.70.6` -- @react-native-community/cli@9.3.2

- **package.json**

> {
> "name": "KonselingTelyu",
> "version": "0.0.1",
> "private": true,
> "scripts": {
> "android": "react-native run-android",
> "ios": "react-native run-ios",
> "start": "react-native start",
> "test": "jest",
> "lint": "eslint ."
> },
> "dependencies": {
> "@firebase/firestore": "^3.12.0",
> "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
> "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.5.0",
> "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^17.5.0",
> "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.2",
> "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
> "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.10",
> "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
> "firebase": "^9.16.0",
> "react": "18.1.0",
> "react-native": "0.70.6",
> "react-native-flash-message": "^0.4.0",
> "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
> "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
> "react-native-image-picker": "^5.0.1",
> "react-native-restart": "^0.0.24",
> "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
> "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
> "react-native-svg": "^13.6.0",
> "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
> "react-native-update-cli": "^1.11.0",
> "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.7",
> "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
> "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
> },
> "devDependencies": {
> "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
> "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
> "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
> "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
> "eslint": "^7.32.0",
> "jest": "^26.6.3",
> "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
> "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
> },
> "jest": {
> "preset": "react-native"
> }
> }

Comment: the same issue, I face this issue when build turns 2, I must clean the project to rebuild to fix this. But this way lost many time

Comment: I face this issue when add lib: @react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this situation, and in order to save time, I executed the following command:

```
rm -rf ./android/app/release
```

I am using Android Studio to generate an APK, so the directory mentioned is `/android/app/release`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for days but i was able to resolve it  by using  `yarn install expo@^48.0.0`  to upgrade my expo project and `npx expo install --fix` to fix all dependencies to match the SDK 48.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: you need to know that we use `yarn add` for installing dependencies.